# Why putStrLn of zio didn't output

Tags: scala, zio

Why putStrLn in flatMap followed by a result statement didn't get effectively write to stdout?

```scala
object Mgr extends App {

  def main1(args: Array[String]) = getStrLn.flatMap { s =>
    putStrLn(s)  // Why this did not write to console?
     UIO.succeed(s)
  }

  override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[zio.ZEnv, Int] = main1(Array()).fold(_ => 1,
    { x =>
       println(x)  // only this line wrote to console, why?
      0
    })
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is basically, that you put two effects into single flatMap.

By invoking `putStrLn(s)` you're not actually printing to console, you're merely creating the description of the action that will print when your program is interpreted and run (when method `run` is called). And because in your flatmap only last value is returned (in your case `UIO.succeed(s)`), then only it will be taken into consideration while constructing ZIO program.

You can fix your program by chaining both actions.

You can do it with `*>` operator:

```
def main1(args: Array[String]) = getStrLn.flatMap { s =>
    putStrLn(s)  *>  UIO.succeed(s)
}
```

or you could just put effects into separate flatMaps. But since you want to create side-effect (by printing value), but then pass value further unchanged, you need to use special function `tap`:

```
def main1(args: Array[String]) = getStrLn.tap { s =>
    putStrLn(s)
}.flatMap { s =>
    UIO.succeed(s)
}
```

Your issue is also described (with other pitfalls) in this [great article](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/5-pitfalls-to-avoid-when-starting-to-work-with-zio-adefdc7d2d5c) (look at the first point).

Comment: Good explanation, but the 2nd code snippet does not compile.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't check it. I fixed it, thaks for remark :)